# Authorize users for specific pages and/or categories

Tags: user-roles, capabilities

I am managing a Wordpress website for a local sports club, the navigation is something like this:

- home
- division

  - archery
  - soccer

    - youth
    - senior
  - volleyball
- ...

I want to enable the people in charge of a division to edit the content of their divisions page and subpages (e.g. person responsible for soccer can change the pages soccer, soccer-youth and soccer-senior), but not the pages for other divisions.

Is this possible with out of the box functionality? Or is there an extension I need?

Bonus question: These users can write blog posts, too ... can I block some of the categories, so they don't see/can't choose them for their blog posts?

Comment: Seems the normality for me: An author can _edit_posts_ but not like an editor _edit_others_posts_. Did I miss something?

Comment: This may be normal, but I never used it ... so I should set the role of the user to "author"? And how do I assign the user to the page? Can I assign him even though I created the page for him? ... If you have a link to a tutorial I would gladly accept it as answer ...

Comment: I now created as user as "author" and set him as the author of two pages. But when I log in as the user, he can only create posts, but cannot change the two pages (doesn't see the menu item "pages" at all) ...

Comment: Let me know if the code I provided was helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An author can *edit_posts* but can not *edit_pages*. Personally I prefer in such a case to create a new role which gets the [capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) as needed. A quick shot for a solution of your problem in a custom plugin would be:

```
namespace WPSE\realloc;

function activate( $network_wide ) {
    add_role(
        'division',
        __( 'people in charge of a division' ), 
        array(
            'read'       => true,
            'edit_pages' => true,
            'edit_posts' => true,
        )
    );
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, __NAMESPACE__ . '\\activate' );

function remove_meta_box() {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        remove_meta_box( 'categorydiv', 'post', 'side' );
    }
}
add_action( 'do_meta_boxes', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\remove_meta_box' );
```

And you can like in my example decide to [remove the meta_box](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box) of the category selector if your normal users should not choose the category of their posts.

Comment: Hi, thanks, that helped. But instead of the code I found an plugin, called "User Role Editor", that did the job for me.